# A SELECT statement for Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this table:
id,bookmarkID,tagID
I want to fetch the top N bookmarkIDs for a given list of tags.
Does anyone know a very fast solution for this? the table is quite large(12 million records)
I am using MySql

Comment: By doing a "TOP" n records, it typically means you are doing an order by by some key metric, or do you just want to LIMIT the first N number of records.  Additionally, what sample of "TAGS" are you looking for.

Comment: Could you give more information about the data, such as a table schema? And what do you mean by "top N bookmarksIDs"?

Comment: how fast is 'very fast'? also, define top (define sort order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tagID,itagID)
ORDER BY bookmarkID ASC
LIMIT n;
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the relational tag to bookmark data is structured. Ideally, each tag is mapped to one or more bookmarks which is essentially a huge reverse index of tags to bookmarks. If that is the case, you can fetch all rows that map tag to bookmark and from that apply a basic scoring function accross your results.

You could probably base it on the [lucene scoring algorithm](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/advanced-topics/scoring.html) that includes the use/spread of the tag across the entire corpus, the density of tags for a given bookmark and some sort of normalizing factor based on when it was bookmarked.

Answer (score 0):

I mainly operate in MSSQL but I think something along the lines of this should work out for you:

```
SELECT bookmarkID
FROM myTable
WHERE tagID in ('tag1,tag2,tag3')
ORDER BY bookmarkID ASC
LIMIT 0,n
```

I could be wrong though, please let me know :)